# How to check for null for a key in@Cacheable?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-el, spring-cache

Is there a way to check if marketCoverage is null before calling market.getValue() in statement mentioned below ?

```
@Cacheable(value = "issuerCache",key="#zip + #county + #marketCoverage.getValue + T(com.hcentive.utils.PlanYearContextHolder).getPlanYear()")
```

```
@Cacheable(value = "issuerCache",key="#zip + #county + #marketCoverage!=null?marketCoverage.getValue:null + T(com.hcentive.utils.PlanYearContextHolder).getPlanYear()")
```

tried this but it seems to not work.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure parameters to an annotation must be constants.